# Get ConcurrentModificationException when createRow() with Apache POI within multi-threads method evem I have already syncronized this code.

Tags: apache-poi, concurrentmodification

I use multi-threads to create rows in excel with Apache POI package.
       Each thread will create a row . to avoid the concurrency issue, I out the code inside the synchronized block to make sure there is only one thread can create a row and cell at the same time.  however I still get an  "ConcurrentModificationException". When code is running,  I can reproduce the exception in the same place where code is processing.

```
the exception is 
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.TreeMap$NavigableSubMap$SubMapIterator.nextEntry(TreeMap.java:1703)
        at java.util.TreeMap$NavigableSubMap$SubMapEntryIterator.next(TreeMap.java:1751)
        at java.util.TreeMap$NavigableSubMap$SubMapEntryIterator.next(TreeMap.java:1745)
        at java.util.TreeMap$NavigableSubMap$EntrySetView.size(TreeMap.java:1637)
        at java.util.TreeMap$NavigableSubMap.size(TreeMap.java:1507)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.createRow(XSSFSheet.java:777)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.createRow(XSSFSheet.java:149)
        at com.citi.mrr.rootquery.RootQueryThread.writeQueryResultToRow(RootQueryThread.java:157)
        at com.citi.mrr.rootquery.RootQueryThread.run(RootQueryThread.java:42)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
```

My code is :

```
@Override
public void run() {
...
    //add row to excel sheet
    synchronized(this){

        Row row = sheet.createRow(querySequence+1); // here I get exception

        row.createCell(0).setCellValue( rqResult.getRQName());
       ..
     }
```

}

Thanks for any help.

Comment: [Apache poi FAQ N10224](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10224): "Handling different document-objects in different threads will work. Accessing the same document in multiple threads will not work.". If you look at [XSSFSheet.java](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.java?view=markup), you see that it uses a `TreeMap` `_rows` which is not synchronized.

Comment: hi， Axel. Thanks for the comments.   you mentioned, "Accessing the same document in multiple threads will not work." , I agree on this, so I add "synchronized(this){"  block outside the   "sheet.createRow()" .  is this guaranty only one thread will access this document at any time?  then should no Concurrent modification problem.     Thanks again for answering.

Comment: "Is this guaranty only one thread will access this document?": No, it only guarantees that the method `public void run()` will be synchronized. A `*.xlsx` file (as well as other Office Open XML files) is a `ZIP` archive containing the content of the `Excel` workbook in different files within a directory structure. This `ZIP` archive is handled by `apache poi` within a [ZipPackage](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/ZipPackage.html) in memory. All modifications on this `ZipPackage` in memory would must be synchronized. This is not trivial and most times not meaningful.

Comment: Axel, Thanks!  I am clear now.